# Youtube Unity Lens Returns No Results On 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, lenses, youtube

I'm having trouble with getting access to Youtube's content via the Unity lens. I thought it was my computer's proxy problem in general, however Wikipedia and Ask Ubuntu lenses both are able to connect.

Youtube lens shows the general "sorry there is nothing that matches your search" message. Any one experienced this before? Any ideas?

I couldn't find anyone having the same problem on here so decided to open up a new question.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: same problem, tried purging ppa's, logout and the like, no change.